# Difference between asynchronous mechanisms in different languages

Tags: asynchronous

Until recently I only knew about NodeJS like mechanism for asynchronous. Apparently Python and C++ uses something called co-routines. Rust tokio is using work-stealing scheduler. In Java (versions before 19), as I have heard, the code has to be in separate units, for instance, I have to separate calculations from time consuming IO when using Async programming.

I would like to know other types of mechanisms used for Async programming in languages and differences between them in terms of things happening under the hood. If I'm correct about Java async, I would like to know why I have to break the code in to small units which is not necessary in like NodeJS, in terms of performance.

Comment: What exactly does "*the code has to be in separate units*" mean? Where did you read that?

Comment: Do you know how asynchrony in JS and Python worked before the introduction of `async`/`await` syntax?